# Can I send a Complex Object with Properties that themselves are objects to a FromBody param in Core Web API?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to post an object from an Angular post to an ASP.Net MVC Core Web API Post method.

The Angular function looks like this:

```
        $scope.addAction = function (pAction, pCaseId) {
            pAction.caseId = pCaseId;

            $http.post(actionUrl, pAction)
              .then(function (response) {
                $scope.data.actions.push(response.data);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                $scope.data.ActionInsertError = error;
              });
        }
```

Everything is getting built exactly the way I want right before the POST:

[image]

Here is the .Net Core Web API POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Generic.Model.Lerd.Action> Post([FromBody]ActionFromBodyModel model)
{
    long result;
    Generic.Model.Lerd.Action action;
    using (var conn = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("INSERT INTO Actions ");
            sb.Append("(ActionStatus, ActionTypeId, CaseId, DateCreated, Notes) ");
            sb.Append("VALUES ");
            sb.Append("(@ActionStatus, @ActionTypeId, @CaseId, @DateCreated, @Notes); ");
            sb.Append("SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);");

            command.CommandText = sb.ToString();

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ActionStatus", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = model.ActionStatus });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ActionTypeId", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = model.ActionTypeId });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CaseId", SqlDbType.BigInt) { Value = model.CaseId });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DateCreated", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = DateTime.Now });
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Notes", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = model.Notes });

            try
            {
                result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                action = await _genericService.GetSingleIncludingAsync(result,
                    a => a.ActionType);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }

    return action;
}
```

Here is the FromBody model:

```
public class ActionFromBodyModel
{
    public long CaseId { get; set; }
    public long ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    public long ActionStatus { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

I can get my top level properties here:

[image]

Now I try to get the ActionType1 object from pCase in the Angular Post to the Web API Post.

So I add that property into the FromBody model:

```
public class ActionFromBodyModel
{
    public long CaseId { get; set; }
    public long ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    public long ActionStatus { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public ActionType1 ActionType1 { get; set; }
}
```

ActionType1 looks like this:

```
public class ActionType1 : BaseEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public long ActionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Action Action { get; set; }

     public long ActionProposedBySupervisorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ActionProposedBySupervisorId")]
    public LookupDetail ActionProposedBySupervisor { get; set; }

    public long ActionTakenBySupervisorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ActionTakenBySupervisorId")]
    public LookupDetail ActionTakenBySupervisor { get; set; }

    public DateTime ActionEffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

But when I add this property in, my whole FromBody object is null on the post.
I'm not even getting the top level properties.

Is there a way to post complex objects like this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my naming was off from Angular model to backend model.

I just tacked on Id to most of my properties in the Angular model to match backend model on my ng-model attributes in the form.